# What is "outbearded"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, adjectives

I was reading Scott's *Woodstock* the other day, and came upon the word *outbearded*. Searching with Google reveals [nothing relevant](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=dictionary+outbearded&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk) and I am wondering what it means.

The context is that Everard and a youth, Kerneguy (King Charles in disguise) are quarrelling, and are barely able to remain civil to each other:-

> Everard, on the other hand, stung beyond his patience, and from the
>   grace and composure of the youth's carriage, still conceiving him to
>   be either Wilmot or some of his compeers in rank and profligacy,
>   returned to the town of Woodstock, determined not to be *outbearded*,
>   even though he should seek redress by means which his principles
>   forbade him to consider as justifiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the contextual meaning [in these examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22outbearded%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1833,cd_max:1871&lr=lang_en#q=%22outbearded%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1833,cd_max:1871,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=o6JvTriVCIbtrAffhYn_Bg&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4dbcf4f11484ba2&biw=1024&bih=581), to *be outbearded* is a somewhat poetic expression that means *to be defeated/to be outdone.*

This link references Sir Walter Scott again in explaining the origin of the expression *[to beard a lion in his (own) den.](http://www.word-detective.com/2010/07/29/beard-to/)*

According [to this Ngram lookup,](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=outbearded&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) *outbearded* is not in vogue. (Is *worsted* still used to mean *defeated*? Or is it a type of suit?)

Also see [this link](http://reiterations.blogspot.com/2005/12/outbearded.html) which uses 'outbearded.'

Comment: Well, you are right, of course. But your ["in these examples"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22outbearded%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1833,cd_max:1871&lr=lang_en#q=%22outbearded%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1833,cd_max:1871,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=o6JvTriVCIbtrAffhYn_Bg&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4dbcf4f11484ba2&biw=1024&bih=581) consists of 18 hits. That's 15 repeats of the same Scott passage as quoted by OP, plus a couple that seem to be OCR mis-scannings of "outboarded". There's really only a single other valid instance. **TL;DR: It's a rare word**

Answer (score 3):

[Beard (v)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beard):

> **7.** to oppose boldly; defy: *It took courage for the mayor to beard the pressure groups.*

To be *outbearded* would therefore mean to be opposed to the point at which you cannot adequately/convincingly be defiant back.  Or, for a synonym, *outdone*.

Comment: ...unless town is Woodstock, NY, and the year is 1969

Answer (score 1):

Bearded has another archaic meaning to "confront boldy" - literally "in your face" which is presumably where the use for face-fur came from .